# How to present different navigation title when large title collapse?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

Currently, I have large titles enabled for the navigation bar with the following code in the viewdidLoad of the ViewController:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
let result = formatter.string(from: date)

self.title = "This is a Test\n\(result)"

var count = 0
for item in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
    for sub in item.subviews {
        if sub is UILabel {
            if count == 1 {
                break;
            }
            let titleLab :UILabel = sub as! UILabel
            titleLab.numberOfLines = 0
            titleLab.text = self.title
            titleLab.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
}
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutSubviews()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

How can I present a completely different title when the navigation bar is collapsed in a "normal state" where the bar is no longer large?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can **`observe` the `bounds`** of the `navigationBar` and change the `title` using a check on the `height` of the `navigationBar`.

**1.** for **Small Title**, `height` of `navigationBar` **= 44**

**2.** for **Large Title**, `height` of `navigationBar` **> 44**

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.observer = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.observe(\.bounds, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (navigationBar, changes) in
            if let height = changes.newValue?.height {
                if height > 44.0 {
                    //Large Title
                    self.title = "Large Title"
                } else {
                    //Small Title
                    self.title = "Small Title"
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick side question, if you notice my original code splits the title into two rows: self.title = `“This is a Test\n\(result)"` Is it possible to make each row a different color?

Comment: Can you please take a look this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569515/change-the-color-of-text-in-this-custom-navigation-bar-with-two-rows

Comment: I found that there were issues with this method when scrolling and navigating in a navigation stack. Observing the frame height instead of the bounds height seems to have fixed it.

Comment: I can confirm that there is an issue with observing bounds, it shows 45, 46, 47 instead of 44. With  `.frame` works fine.

Comment: Does anyone know about a SwiftUI equivalent to this? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let heightForCollapsedNav = UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.size.height
    let navHeight = navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = navHeight <= heightForCollapsedNav  ? "Collapsed" : "Large"
}
```