# Change the color of text in this custom navigation bar with two rows?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I currently have a navigation bar with large titles enabled that also supports two rows with the following code in the viewdidLoad:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)




        self.title = “This is a Test\n\(result)"



        var count = 0
        for item in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
            for sub in item.subviews{
                if sub is UILabel{
                    if count == 1 {
                        break;
                    }
                    let titleLab :UILabel = sub as! UILabel
                    titleLab.numberOfLines = 0
                    titleLab.text = self.title
                    titleLab.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                    count = count + 1
                }
            }

        }
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutSubviews()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

How can I change the font and color of the text in each row of 
`self.title = “This is a Test\n\(result)"`

For instance, make `"This is a Test"` Black and `"(result)"` gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `attributedString` first from the `string` and add the required `attributes`, i.e.

```
let result = "13 June 2019"
let text = "This is a Test\n\(result)"
let arr = text.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
for (index, str) in arr.enumerated() {
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
    if index == 0 {
        attrStr.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
        attrStr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
    } else {
        attrStr.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
        attrStr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
    }
    if index < arr.count {
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
    }
    attributedString.append(attrStr)
}
```

Create a `UILabel` and add this `attributedString` as `attributedText` of the `label`.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .center
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Add this `label` as the `titleView` of the `navigationItem`, i.e.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Comment: This answer really helped me out a lot, I really appreciate it. Do you mind taking a look at this one? It is similar, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56613252/11349745