# Can I make large rightBarButtonItem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

What I have: 
[image]

```
self.title = "Title"
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
```

Is it possible to make this `Add` looks exactly like this `Title`?
Something like this: 
[image]

Or any other solution for this - title left - button with image right, same heights?

Comment: keep in mind large title is dynamic during scrolling placing left button with such sizes will stay there and block a good amount of content behind the navigationbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717269/how-to-create-a-left-aligned-title-with-preferslargetitles-in-navigationbar/63717683#63717683) answer which shows how you can manage Navigation bar title when collapsed and when it's large. It won't give you an exact answer but it will definitely help you in achieving what you want.

Other then that please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073738/change-size-of-uibarbuttonitem-image-in-swift-3) answer which will help you understand how give x,y positions to right bar button item.

Just a quick overview how you can achieve what you want by the combination of this two answers:-

1. Set the position of the right bar button item according to the position or height of the navigation bar which you wanted to do. Link number 2 will help you in doing that.
2. Observe your navigation bar when the height of your navigation bar is increased or decreased you can change the position of your right bar button item.

and Done. By using this you can manage the position of your bar button item at both the item when your Navigation bar is Enlarged at that time you can show button at different position and when the Navigation Bar is collapsed you can show button at different position so that it doesn't look vice-versa of your question after changing position of your button.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in my app - not exactly what you are looking for, but should give you enough to go on:

```swift
    func setupNavBar() {
    let rightButton = UIButton()
    rightButton.setTitle("Leave", for: .normal)
    rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(rightButton)
    rightButton.tag = 97
    rightButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: 120, height: 20)

    let targetView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightButton, attribute:
        .trailingMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: targetView,
                         attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -16)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: targetView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -6)
    rightButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint])
    }
```

[image: Custom Right Button]

I also created this function to remove it (hence the tag use above):

```swift
    func removeRightButton(){
        guard let subviews = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews else{
            log.info("Attempt to remove right button but subviews don't exist")
            return
        }
        for view in subviews{
            if view.tag == 97 {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```