# Is it possible to assign a ViewController to a SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am building an SwiftUI app with the SwiftUI app protocol.

I need to access some UIKIt functions, particularly the ones that control NavigationView as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555928/13727105.

Apparently, to do that I need to bind my SwiftUI view with a ViewController.

I've tried doing the following:

`ContentView.swift`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ContentViewIntegratedController() // <- here
            NavigationView{
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Content View")
                        .navigationTitle("Content View")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

struct ContentViewIntegratedController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        return ContentViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContentViewIntegratedController>) {}
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

but calling `ContentViewIntegratedContoller` (on line 5) seems to create a new preview instead of modifying the existing one.

Is there anyway to integrate a ViewController to modify a SwiftUI view?

**What I don't want to do:**

- Create a Storyboards app with SwiftUI views in it
- Create a Storyboards view for `ContentViewIntegratedViewController`.

Is there any alternative ways I could access those functions without adding a ViewController to my SwiftUI view?

TIA.

Comment: @Andrew I did. ``ContentViewIntegratedViewController`` extends a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. But it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want Storyboards based app you should create project with UIKit-based template and then integrate SwiftUI views in it using `UIHostingController`

Comment: Looking at the linked question, what you want to do is a bit more tricky than simply using a UIKit view with SwiftUI.  You want to access the properties of the navigation controller that underpins the `NavigationView`.  I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in pure SwiftUI to directly detect the changing between `large` and `inline` display modes. However, using [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), you can drop down into UIKit to solve this.

I solved this by getting the view for the large title, and detecting when the `alpha` property changed. This changes at the exact moment when the title changes from `large` to `inline`, or vice-versa.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
    @State private var title: String = "Large Title"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Text("Hello world!")
            }
            .navigationTitle(title)
        }
        .introspectNavigationController { nav in
            let largeTitleView = nav.navigationBar.subviews.first { view in
                String(describing: type(of: view)) == "_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView"
            }
            observer = largeTitleView?.observe(\.alpha) { view, change in
                let isLarge = view.alpha == 1
                title = isLarge ? "Large Title" : "Inline title"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: This method surely works but the compact title changes to large title for a split second which is something I'd want to avoid. 
There is a new [insert Swift jargon] called Toolbar. Is there anyway to observe the change in the alpha value of the toolbar?

Comment: @PraantoSamadder I don't believe there is a way to fix this. It's due to the observer being called _after_ the navigation bar display mode has changed.

Answer (score 3):

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ContentViewIntegratedController(view: YourView())
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    }




--------------------------------------------------------------
    struct YourView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
        Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }}
------------------------------------------------------
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentViewIntegratedController :UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    
    var view: YourView
    
    init(view:YourView) {
        self.view = view
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController{
        
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        let controller =     UINavigationController(rootViewController:childView)
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        let searchController = UISearchController()
        
        
        searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
        
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(.red))
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.compactAppearance = appearance
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.standardAppearance = appearance
        

        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "navigation bar"
        controller.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Rechercher...", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
        searchController.searchBar.setValue("Annuler", forKey: "cancelButtonText")
        
        
        searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .white
        
        let sfConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 30)
        let barCodeIcon = UIImage(systemName: "barcode.viewfinder")?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal).withConfiguration(sfConfiguration)
    

        searchController.searchBar.setImage(barCodeIcon, for: .bookmark, state:.normal)
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
  

        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
       
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.searchController = searchController
        
        return controller
        
    }
    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {
        
    }}
```

[image: Example]