# Is it possible to observe the alpha of the toolbar of a SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am writing a SwiftUI app where I need to have different texts inside the large and compact navigationBar title.

My approach was to observe the change in alpha values of the toolbar using Swift-Introspect as shown below but that met no luck.

I tried to achieve this by trying to attach a ViewController to my `ContentView` with no luck as in here: [Is it possible to assign a ViewController to a SwiftUI view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219001/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-viewcontroller-to-a-swiftui-view/69236056#69236056)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var titleString: String = ""
    @State private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Some Random Text Again")
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .padding().padding(.leading)

                    }.navigationTitle("Large Title")
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                                Text(titleString)
                            }
                        }
                        .introspectNavigationController {nav in
                            let toolbarView = nav.toolbar
                            self.observer = toolbarView?.observe(\.alpha, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (toolbar, changes) in
                                if toolbar.alpha == 1 {
                                    self.titleString = "Inline Text"
                                } else {
                                    self.titleString = "Toolbar is Hidden"
                                }
                            })
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The process above seems to not be working. Is there any better way to observe the change in the alpha value of the toolbar?

Comment: are you asking how to change the opacity of the text inside the toolbar?

Comment: @workingdog Not the text inside the toolbar but the entire toolbar itself.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226636/13727105 - As in this answer, the user is observing the change in the alpha of the large navbar text. 
I was hoping to do something similar but with the entire toolbar instead.